# Automatic generation of attribute, taking the value from another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, point-in-polygon

I have points within different villages and I want to have the village name automatically be added to the point layer when I click within that polygon rather than using join by location or manually typing in the name of the village.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) and create a [virtual field](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#creating-a-virtual-field): one that is automatically updated. So when you create a point or move it, it will run the expression again to update the value. Use this expression to transfer the value of attribute field `village_name_field` from polygon layer `village_layer_name` to your point layer (name of polygon the point lies within):

`overlay_within ('village_layer_name', "village_name_field")[0]`

*Replace `village_layer_name` and `villag_name_field` with the layer- and fieldname you use.*

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Add a new field to the point layer, same type as the polygon field.
2. Go to Layer Properties - Attributes Form - Drag and drop designer, drag the newly added field from Available Widgets to Form Layout.
3. At the bottom set the default value as:

`overlay_intersects(layer:='district', expression:="kommunnamn")[0]`, change district to the name of your polygon layer and kommunnamn to the name of the attribute you want to join.

Check "Apply default value on update"

When you add new point feature it will fetch the attribute from the intersecting polygon.

[image]